# One-liner to get flat list of files from a list of possible directories?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, directory

Suppose we have a list of directories, *some of which might not exist*:

```
dirs = ['dir1','dir2','dir3']
```

For sake of argument only two exist and their content is:

```
dir1
  --file1a
  --file1b
dir2
  --file2a
  --file2b
```

**What is the best one-liner to get a *flat* list of all the files?** The closest I got was:

```
import os
files = [ os.listdir(x) for x in ['dir1','dir','dir3'] if os.path.isdir(x) ]
```

But that gives me a nested list:

```
[['file1a','file1b'],['file2a','file2b']]
```

What one-liner do I have to use instead, if I want that to be `['file1a', 'file1b', 'file2a', 'file2b']`?

Comment: Shall we assume a single level of depth or an arbitrary number of levels?

Comment: Single level, please. `[x for sublist in [ os.listdir(x) for x in ['dir1','dir','dir3'] if os.path.isdir(x) ] for x in sublist]` seems a bit rough.

Comment: @61612 I did just now and ad I expected, it's different. No folders involved. No condition for existence.

Comment: @61612 if it is so simple, post a quick answer. That will cut ghis discussion short. BTW he provided a possible answer to his own question in a comment above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can chain the items into a single list:

```
from itertools import chain as ch


files = list(ch.from_iterable(os.listdir(x) for x in ['dir1', 'dir', 'dir3'] if os.path.isdir(x)))
```

shortest I can make it:

```
from itertools import chain as ch, ifilter as ifil, imap 
from os import path, listdir

files = list(ch.from_iterable(imap(listdir, ifil(path.isdir, ('dir1', 'dir', 'dir3')))))
```

If you just want to use the names then just iterate over the chain object.

Comment: Still a bit long, but doesn't seem to get simpler. Thank you!

Comment: @con-f-use, made it as short as possible without being completely obscure

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why a one-liner is what you want, but here:

```
files = [path for dir_lst in map(os.listdir, filter(os.path.isdir, ['dir1','dir','dir3'])) for path in dir_lst]
```

This filters the non-directories first (using `filter`), it then `map`s the `os.listdir` on what was left, and aggregates using two `for` loops.